# Download Option on hover over in Picture Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

To download a picture from the picture library my client needs to select an image, click the 3 dots, again click the 3 dots and then click on Download a Copy.

This seems to be a tedious process for them. What I require is a download option as soon as I mouse over on the thumbnail. Is this possible?

can we have an option for downloading multiple images from the share-point picture library

Comment: Why tag with Sharepoint Designer? What is your SharePoint version?  And the "Also can we have..." is a different topic altogether that cannot be answered in the same question. Please start a new question for that topic.

Comment: Please Help me to answer this query

Comment: provide more context.

Comment: when we mouse over on any image thumbnail, we see the details about the image. i was successful in hiding the details. Now i want an option for download to come when we mouseover on the image thumbnail so that the extra effort of clicking on the 3 dots etc.. is eliminated. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done. But the problem with the work around which I have figured out is not actually anywhere related to SharePoint.

In order to accomplish the requirement of yours, first of all, I have added **[Hover Zoom Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hover-zoom/nonjdcjchghhkdoolnlbekcfllmednbl?hl=en)** in my **[Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/features.html?brand=CHBD&gclid=Cj0KCQjwnazLBRDxARIsAECdauvBlY1gYc1MKHU-mfL6EGyXnFvcpGFBqYTpv9GgISAr1tOM812pThAaAsTuEALw_wcB&dclid=CPLBiPbLj9UCFVxmjgodWJANxw)** browser. 
[image]

Now, I have set the view of the *Picture Library* to *All Pictures*, in which the images are displayed in the *list view*.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now, when I hover on any of the images, the image will be displayed in a pop up and if I have to download that image, then all I have to do is tap the **S button in the keyboard** and the image will be **downloaded**.